# how can i accept react component constructor as a function param in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
import { Component} from "react";

export class Test extends Component<{}, {}> {
      render() {
        return "Hello";
      }
    }

    function myFunction<P, S, C extends Component<P, S>>(c: C): void {
      console.log("ctor", c);
    }

    const s = myFunction(Test);
```

**Error :**

> Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Component<{}, {}>'.   Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof
>   Test'. 07:35:53 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

do i need to implement all members of original react `Component` class using super.(..) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to declare the type of `C` as something that extends a newable function returning a component:

```
import { Component} from "react";

export class Test extends Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

function myFunction<P, S, C extends new () => Component<P, S>>(c: C): void {
    console.log("ctor", c);
}

const s = myFunction(Test);
```

Comment: still getting error!, error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Component<{}, {}>'.

Comment: @invariant thats interesting. The same snippet doesn't give me any errors when I compile it. In fact I can even write `var x: new () => Component = Test` without issue. Not sure why there is a difference between our results. What is your typescript version?

Comment: > tsc -v  = Version 2.6.2

Comment: Hmm. Updated mine to the same, still no issue. Is this an error you see in your IDE or in the actual `tsc` command output?

Comment: @invariant Wait a minute I just had a thought. Your example class has no constructor and so the newable function takes no parameters. But does your actual implementation have constructor args? If so, you might try `new (...args: any[]) => Component<P, S>` instead. EDIT: Or for more type safety `new (props: P, state: S) => Component<P, S>`.